# Printing a String ( character pointer ) using Printf directly - Weird behaviour

Tags: c, string, for-loop, printf, scanf

In the following  c code the 'line 10' doesn't print anything when ln8 & lb9 are removed. It just takes the input and prints nothing. But the weird thing is on addition of those 2 lines, the code works perfectly fine i.e the input string got printed twice once by for loop and once by the printf statement in ln10. (What i am trying to do is just print the input String)
I use MinGw Compiler and ran code using cmd.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMPLP.png)

```
int main()
{
 char *s;
 scanf("%s",s);

 printf("Line 9:\t");
 for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) //line 8

 printf("%c",*(s+i)); //line 9

 printf("\nLine 12:\t%s\n",s); //line10
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is certanly an interesting problem but non of the c langauge. You see `char *s;` declares a pointer to memory location. But since you do not initialize it the pointer is undefined. So it is pointed who knows where in memory. And `scanf` will store the string there, but since it is who knows where it is not protected from change and so it might be change between operations. This all boils down to: You used an _uninitialized_ variable, which leeds to undefined behaviour. And this means any change (recompiling, exceuting on another machine, ...) leeds to different behaviour.

Comment: As a note always compile with the flag `-Wall` which would have told you that you use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Thank you! It gave me a warning that s is uninitialized in scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *s
```

you declare a pointer but do not allocate for it. It's undefined. Because the undefined behavior, everything can happen. (for example, When i test your program in my PC, it raises `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

You have to allocate for the pointer before scanf (do not forget to free `s` when you do not need to use it):

```
char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN); // MAX_LEN: you define its value.
```

Or you can use the array of character:

```
char s[100]; // here, the string length is up to 99;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try initializing the s using strdup.

```
int main()
{
 char *s = strdup("");
 scanf("%s",s);

 printf("\nLine 12:\t%s\n",s); //line10
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now `s` points to an empty string of just 1 char. That will probably not be enough.

Comment: I tested it. It worked with this. Can you also please try and test it.

Comment: That is because the memory allocator _may_ have allocated more than just one char, so an error is not apparent.But is is wrong never the less.

Comment: Try testing with `"thisisaverylongstringthatshouldcauseanerrorbecauseIdidnotreadmylecturenotesonstrings"`

Comment: Just tested it on my program and its working. I added few more characters also. It still worked. Btw I am using vs2017 for testing this. The issue was the initialization of char *s, I just mentioned a way of doing it.

Comment: Dear psingh, it is not about "it works", it is about that you don't understand that you may only use memory that is yours and that your `strdup` call allocates just one char, so anything more than one char _is wrong_.